# How to Create Shift+F5 event in vb

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a Shift+F5 key press event in VB.net. I used this code for creating Shift+F5 event in vb but it is not working.

```
Private Sub IBR_SJK_P110_000_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Select Case e.Modifiers
        Case Keys.Shift
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
                MsgBox("Shift F5 Pressed")
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

But if i used

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
```

than It is working well.

Please Help me.

Comment: Why don't you try using some API functions ? like GetAsyncKeyState ?And of course it won't work .. because you are firstly firing a button like Shift , and after that F5.Second fire case won't be caught...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But How can i use it. I never use it before.

Comment: This is a reffernce to the API i specified before .... http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate

Comment: I might be wrong, but are you trying to detect when specifically the stop debugging button is pressed to close the program rather than any other method like clicking the close button? If you are, sorry that's not possible within the program - vs stops the code execution immediately.

Comment: unless of course you are writing a VS plug-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example :

```
 If e.KeyData = (Keys.F5 and Keys.Shift) Then
                MessageBox.Show("got here")
 End If
```

Comment: This does not apply to the `KeyDown` event. Also, the keys are to be combined using bitwise `And`, not `+`.

Comment: Yup you're right .. and who said something about "key down" .This is an example

Comment: Possibly because the OP is using the KeyDown event

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can attempt is this:

```
If e.Shift = True AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
    MsgBox("Shift F5 Pressed")
End If
```

The `e.Modifiers` property seems to be bugged on some computers/with some keyboards...